Did you read vs Have you read to refer to life experience
*Context 1: I saw this dialogue in a movie.

A: You acted like a character in X novel. Did you read X novel?
B: No, I haven't.
A: Let me tell you about that novel, the main character is a nice
girl.......

I think that It should be "Have you read X novel?" to refer to life experience .
*Context 2: This afternoon, I visited my American friend's house, I actually heard he said "Did you see the X movie?" :

A: Did you see X movie?
B: No, I haven't.
A: That is a great movie, you should watch.

I think that It should be "Have you seen X movie?" to refer to life experience .
Is that in the US, natives also use simple past to refer to life experience?
Is that American speakers can use simple past and present perfect interchangeably in this context?

People say things, and scripts capture the dialog, that make sense at the moment, not in a book about language. See? These examples are not unusual in conversation.

As a British English speaker I agree with you (that 'Have you read the book?' sounds correct, and 'Did you?' sounds jarringly American). Some American posters will tell me that this isn't true and that they use both forms. Even here in the UK in recent times we see adverts saying "[Our product] just got better".

We don't know the full context. There is nothing grammatically or pragmatically wrong with a simple past there. What movie, by the way? And reading a book is not specifically life experience.

Simple past is used of discrete events or actions in the past, but it can be used with seeing a  movie. The questioner may phrase the question to ask not whether the movie is part of your life experience but whether you saw the movie when it was showing in theaters or being "aired" on the various streaming services.  The person asking might not even be aware of this as a choice they made. Who knows what they were thinking in the moments before they asked the question?  Maybe not even the speaker knows this!
For most of the past century, movies came and went. You had a window of opportunity to see them when they were in the theater. With the advent of inexpensive and ubiquitous storage and playback media (tape, DVD, now streaming) that situation has radically changed, but there is still the lingering sense that a movie will be in the theaters for only a brief time. And the phrases one uses when asking about movie-seeing developed throughout the 20th century. They're like "canned" questions sitting on the shelf ready to be used. Language doesn't change as fast as technology does. We still measure car engines using horsepower units, right?
Thus, someone who asks:

Did you see Oppenheimer?

might have in mind "when it was in theaters" recently.
and someone who asks:

Have you seen Oppenheimer?

might want to know if you've seen it and know how it goes.
P.S. As far as the novel question is concerned, a number of circumstances could justify simple past, Did you read the novel?, and what they would have in common is that the speaker wants to know whether the person spent time reading it, actually read it, not whether they made it part of their "cultural experience":

Did you read the novel, or merely a study guide of some kind?
You're new at this publishing house. It has come to my attention that you recently rejected a submission called All Thumbs, an epistolary novel composed entirely of text messages. Did you read it or reject it out of hand as some kind of a joke?


I understand what you explained about the movie example. How do you explain the use of simple past in the novel example?

@LE123: See the P.S.

There's even the expression "Did you catch [this movie]," emphasizing the fleeting opportunity.

But I only want to know in the context I provided, As I see, there is no specific time, so the simple past is wrong. Right?

@LE123  It's not wrong, it's simply in a petri dish, lacking any real-world context.

@LE123 In order to say that it's not the idiomatic way of asking the question, you'd need to paint a more complete picture of the context.  For example, you could show a conversation about the ten best movies of all time. Then it would be clearly Have you seen...?

I would like to add some detail to the context 1. A and B are discussing B's weird behavior last night. Suddenly A realizes that B weird behavior is the same as a character in a novel B has read.

A: You acted like a character in X novel. Did you read X novel?
B: No, I haven't.
A: Let me tell you about that novel, the main character is a nice girl.......

Is "Did you read X novel? " correct to use in this context?

@LE123: "Have you read {novel title}?" is the usual idiomatic way of inquiring whether a particular novel is among the novels a person has read in their lifetime. But It's not "incorrect" to ask Did you read {novel title}?  That form frames the question differently. For example,  if the novel is one that students are typically assigned to read in secondary school,  or the novel in question was very popular and on the best seller list for quite a while and being read in book clubs, a person might ask Did you read {novel title}?"  The questioner might be thinking of the novel in that light.

"Did you" is simple past, "have you" is present perfect
See https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/eb/qa/did-you-buy-vs-have-you-bought
Simple past describes something that has happened and is no longer happening. Present perfect describes something that has happened and is still happening or at least relevant to the present.
For both of your examples, there is no semantic difference, "have" could replace "did", and "didn't" could replace "haven't" without a problem. But sometimes there is a difference:


Simple past:      Why didn’t you send me any messages? (The time for sending messages is over.)

Present perfect:  Why haven’t you sent me any messages? (You can still send me a message.)




The OP asks about the right tense to use to refer to past "life experience". The suggestion is that the correct form is the perfect tense rather than the past tense. I have read X, not I read X.
However I question the whole assumption of this post. Life experience simply talks about events that happened in the past, and all forms of English past tense may be valid depending on context and the intended meaning. To take one example from the OP we might say:

I saw the movie last week.
I have seen three movies in the last year.

The past tense in sentence 1 points backwards to a particular past time. The perfect tense in sentence 2 describes a more extended period of time, and the activity is spread out over that whole period.
There are many other variations. The point here is just to show that all tenses are valid if they say what you want them to say. Context is critical.
And of course, as the comment notes, spoken/casual dialogue in a movie adds a whole other dimension to the topic.

Right, Did you read a book? is really not specifically about "life experience". The action is either done and dusted (simple past) OR a person wants to signal a past action or state of being without implying when at the time of speaking .

You can answer a question in the simple past with an auxiliary from the present perfect. And life experience has nothing to do with it.
What does matter here is this:  Do you mean an activity that is finished? Such as:

Did you see your mother at the street fair? [on hour ago, last week, yesterday, last month]?
Yes, I did.

Bear this in mind: If you use the present perfect, you are signaling the past without being specific about the past in terms of the present time when the question is asked. If it does not matter when something occurred but you want to signal the past, use the present perfect.

John: Have you seen your mother this morning? [It is still morning!]
Mark: Yes, I have.
John: Oh, when did you see her?
Mark: I saw her at 9:00 before she left.

Note: adverbs like recently are used with the present perfect in standard usage. "Have you seen her recently?"
Now, in the question here, a simple past is responded to with an auxiliary from the present perfect, which is fine.
The question here:
A: Did you see X movie? [specific and in the sense of something that is over]
B: No, I haven't. But I hope to.  [haven't signals the past and is not specific about when in the past.]
COMPARE
Yes, I have. I saw it yesterday.
Now, the question here could very well also be in the present perfect:

Have you read this book?
Yes, I have. No I haven't.

There is nothing in the canon that specifies that a question in the simple past is anything other than that. If you are looking to refer to the past without an intended specific time (explicit [last week, yesterday, or implied), by all means use the present perfect. So, the use is dictated, in part, by a speaker's intention. Is the speaker just signaling the past and not interested really in the "when"?
So: You can choose which you want:

Have you seen this movie?
Did you see this movie? [**implied, yesterday etc.]
Did you see this movie last night? [express]

It is true that one hears a lot of: Did you do it yet? As opposed to: Have you done it yet? The standard way to say that is in the present perfect but people speak like they speak. At some point, if 50% percent of the population say it, it becomes grammatical. Is it possible to "prove that"? Probably not. But that's what a lot of linguists say.

I would like to add some detail to the context 1. A and B are discussing a bout B's weird behavior last night. Suddenly A realizes that B weird behavior is the same as a character in a novel B has read.

A: You acted like a character in X novel. Did you read X novel?
B: No, I haven't.
A: Let me tell you about that novel, the main character is a nice girl.......

"Did you read X novel? " is simple past still fine to use in this context?

Because the I think that there are no reason B is thinking of a specific time, so I think that present perfect should be used here instead. But B actually used simple past here (as I saw in the subtitle of a movie).

if B says ""Did you read X novel yet?".  I agree , but B said that question without "yet"? This is not normal. Right?

@LE123 Please reread my next-to-last paragrah and the examples; it should be clear now.  But I repeat: yet is used with the present perfect in standard speech. Have you understood the idea of: It's your choice and why? Versus: DId you understand the idea when you read it? [specific time: when you read it].

[correction: A and B are discussing B's weird behavior, no about]

In my context, A and B discussing about novels in general, when A asking B about the novel, as I see, there is NO implied specific time, so that I think the simple past is not correct in this context. Do you also think so?

In this context, it is fine to use “Did you read X yet?. But it is not fine to use “Did you red X?”

@LE123 Last time: Have you read x yet? Due to yet. I have now repeated this three times. PLEASE reread my answer. The use of one or the other depends on the what the speaker wants.

You said :   "Did you see this movie? [**implied, yesterday etc.]".  But in my context, I can't see any implication of the time indicating "when". If the tense is based on what the speaker wants, so please help me clarify what he wants to express by using the simple past "Did you see this movie?" in this context.

@LE123 Did you see this movie? implies it was specific and that the action is over.
